# Is there a way to add a hyper-link to a discussion board item inside workflow 2010 that reference the flat.aspx view rather than on the DispForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have added a global workflow using sharepoint designer 2013, which is associated with a Discussion content type. now i am tying to add a link inside the workflow which reference the discussion board item `flat.aspx` view, and not the `DispForm.aspx` view. so i did the following:-

1. I add an activity to the workflow to send an email
2. Inside the email i define the following hyper-link `Workflow Context` ---> `Current Item URL`

[image]

3. Now the result is that inside the email i got the following url which will reference the `DispForm.aspx` of the discussion item, while i was hoping to get the url to reference the discussion item inside the flat view `Flat.aspx`

so can anyone adivce if there is a way to add a hyper-link inside the workflow 2010 send email activity, which reference the `Flat.aspx` view instead of `DispForm.aspx` view -other than having to manually build the link-??